Executing a uVision Command in a FUNC Body
We've got a bootloader that scrubs ram on reset.
When Keil Resets the part, the program in RAM is scrubbed.
Is there a way to run/format the following to run the LOAD command in the Reset Function?
FUNC void OnResetExec(void)
{
    LOAD %L INCREMENTAL // Problematic Line 'Syntax Error'
    Setup(); // Setup PC, SP, etc
}

I cant seem to find the syntax in uVision manual to do this.

What does %L mean? (My experience with scripting µVision are some years old.)

@thebusybee %L is just shorthand for path to linker output file

Use the exec() function according to the documentation:
FUNC void OnResetExec(void)
{
    exec("LOAD %L INCREMENTAL");
    Setup(); // Setup PC, SP, etc
}

